# Confuse about pointer and arrays

Tags: c

I have problem regarding the last printf statement why cant we use intarr to print the array it is showing some junk value.

```
int main() { 
    int intArr[],*p,i,n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    p=intArr;
    p=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",p+i);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",intArr[i]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'd be better off using ordinary array notation here, as in `intArr[i]` in your `scanf` loop.  There's no good reason to do pointer arithmetic here.

Comment: At which line do you expect the content of intarr to change? Where do you think that you initialise it?

Comment: You probably meant `int * intArr = p;` **after** `malloc`.

Comment: `int intArr[]` declares an array of size 0 which is not possible in C. This code does not compile. Please post the code you're having problems with and not some made up fake code.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/CheapLightgreyDominspector - Notice that `intArr` is just declared as a pointer (to the first element in the array).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your intent was to use a variable sized array, initializing it after reading `n`:

```
// read 'n'
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);

// create an automatic (temporary) array of size 'n'
// which will be deallocated once it leaves scope
int intArr[n];

// this part is just making it harder for compiler to 
// do static analysis - why not simply use `intArr`?
int * p = intArr;
```

But since you are using `malloc`, you don't need the temporary array at all and could have just used:

```
// read 'n'
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);

// allocate an array of size 'n'
int * p = malloc(n * sizeof *p);

...

// release the memory 
free(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `intArr[]` is never initialized. `malloc()` gives `p` a new value which is the address of the memory slot it allocated for it on line 5 :

```
p=intArr;                       // This is overridden
p=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int)); // by this
```

So, any further call to `intArray` will produce unpredictable output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from :

```
p = intArr;
p = malloc(...);
```

Doing this, the value of `p` is lost on the second line.

You should have written

```
p = malloc(...);
intArr = p;
```

or

```
intArr = malloc(...);
p = intArr;
```

Note:

1. Writting `int intArr[];` does not compile (at least on gcc 8.3) I assume you wrote `int *intArr;`
2. A compiler should have warn you about the problem : with option **`-Wall`**, gcc says:

   > warning: ‘intArr’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

Comment: This reads like recommending to mix arrays and pointer arithmetic or at least tolerating it. One step further towards the source of the problem would probably be more helpful in the long run. (Downvote not by me.)

Answer (score 0):

look at this correction:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    int *p,i,n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    p=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",p+i);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",*(p+i));

    }
    return 0;
}
```

See that this works and there is no purpose of using intArray

Comment: Well, sure.  But they don't have to be using pointer arithmetic either.

Comment: well, agreed. :)